# How to power LILYGO ESP32-S3 1.9" T-Display without USB?

Tags: esp32, usb-c, 5v, boot-configure

Noob question, I'm sure, but - I have one of these little LILYGO ESP32-S3 1.9" T-Display boards. Linked up with my PC, downloaded my code, runs fine, but I can't get the thing to power up from the 5v rail, or through a 5v supply through the li-po connector on the back, as I have with several other ESP32 boards.

Works fine through the USB-C connector, and I'm measuring 5v on the rail when it's running off the USB.

I assume I'm missing something really obvious to do with either booting without a USB being involved or something, but despite spending half a day hunting t'interwebs, and trying various things, I still can't get it to fire up with anything but a USB-C plugged in. I'm stumped!

(I have read something about attaching a capacitor to the "en" button on a different board in order to pull it to ground on boot, but this board has a reset switch which doesn't seem to reset anything unless attached to a USB supply so not sure if it applies in this case.)

This is the [product](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004496543314.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.5.23f638e32RICMa&algo_pvid=d7e12943-7bce-4ace-9582-581435aa9e06&algo_exp_id=d7e12943-7bce-4ace-9582-581435aa9e06-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000030128898262%22%7D&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21GBP%2117.34%2117.34%21%21%21%21%21%4021021d7b16758432423558352d0688%2112000030128898262%21sea%21UK%211871708403&curPageLogUid=vjPPTzDNlj1S) and an image of the pinout is [here](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S49e0b5f973694c679760bff54b3e6ec2U.jpg) in question.

Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction please?

Comment: Did you go through its schematic yet?  Its schematic is publicly available [here](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/T-Display-S3).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm taking a look now, but have to confess I'm a bit out of my depth with this atm. It's new direction I hadn't tried though, so I'll see if it sheds some light. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that has the same issue, here's what I've found with the kind help of VolosProjects from YouTube:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT); // to boot with battery...
  digitalWrite(15, 1);  // and/or power from 5v rail instead of USB
  ...
}
```

Including the code above allows boot with either battery or power on the 5 V pin. LILYGO also advised the same thing (and mentioned that pin 38 can be set to adjust LCD screen brightness).

Pin 15 needs to be set to HIGH (or 1) in order to boot.

Answer (score 0):

This was also one the [product page](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/T-Display-S3) that PCBCrew Engineer linked in the comments:

> Tips:
>
> 1. Use board as delivered. Connect board to usb to computer without touching anything else. Upload the code. The code will start right
>    after download and run. Unplug the board and connect to usb again. The
>    board will not do anything.
> 2. Use board as delivered. Push down boot button. While boot button is pushed, connect usb to computer. Release boot button. Upload the code.
>    The code will not start right after download. Nothing will happen.
>    Unplug the board and connect to usb again.The board will now boot the
>    code. Unplug the board from USB to computer and connect to other power
>    source like LiPO battery. Again the board will start the code. The
>    computer is not needed again.
>
> New code can be loaded to the board by going to step 1 or 2. Both will
> still work.

Comment: Nick S. - Hi, Despite your intro, this *appears* to be a valid answer-attempt. Those points from the GitHub page seem to suggest that someone using that product has to go through a specific sequence of steps, before the board will boot code using another power source (other than USB). || Since you are quoting from someone, please [edit] your post & add a direct link to the source page. Also, to make it possible for people using screen readers & other assistive technology to "read" your post, I recommend you copy & paste the relevant text into your post (use "blockquotes") instead of an image.

Comment: @SamGibson is this better now? And yeah, OP found an answer on their own, this is just a different way of doing what they wanted to do.

Comment: Nick S. & SamGibson - for what it's worth I had tried the Steps 1 & 2 described above with the code I uploaded, but the board wouldn't boot unless powered via the USB (screen dark, no LEDs illuminated, no serial out) . LILYGO have confirmed that they will add the info above to their docs at some point to clarify the steps required to enable booting from other power sources. I'm not sure why this board needs the additional step when other boards I've played with (S2 gen) didn't, but it's an easy fix once you know how :)